# I want to make a function in javascript, that allows a button to show another button

Tags: javascript, html

My goal is to make one button show another.  So, if I click the button  `#tom`, I want it to show another button `#bob`.

My button at the moment looks like this:

```
<button id="1Container" onClick="pickimg(1);"><img style="cursor:pointer;" src="BicycleBlue_kopi.jpg"></button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function replaceContentInContainer(the new buttons name, "1Container") {
    document.getElementById(the new buttons name).innerHTML =
document.getElementById("1Container").innerHTML;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow is not a free code-writing service...

Comment: Yes is did, but that caused the hole document to crash

Comment: Without knowing your button names, we can't be of much help. Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing the problem you are facing in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Posting your broken code will likely allow us to spot the error and fix it! :) For further information, please refer to the [**help article**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) regarding how to ask good questions, and take the [**tour**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the site :)

Answer (score 0):

you can directly use .click function using Id of the button like this

```
$("#1Container").click(function () {
    alert("This is hit");
    });
```